# Calculating watershed runoff with landuse and rainfall data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, watershed, arc-hydro, precipitation

What is the method for computing rasters of total rainfall of a given month, flow accumulation, and land use (runoff coefficient) or soil K factor? I am using ArcMap 10.

Comment: I would like to estimate the amount of run off of a town. Do you have any information how I can start doing this? I need to use spatial analysis tools like you mentioned above. I am not a GIS person, I am just learning on my own.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you will be computing and others you simply need to obtain the data.

- Rainfall: you will need these as input rasters by month. Do you have this data?  You could check out NOAA http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/GIS/GIS_DATA/
- Flow Accumulation: This should be calculated off of a flow direction grid using Spatial Analyst.  Flow direction is based on elevation.  Do you have a DEM for your area, preferably high resolution? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000051000000.htm
- Land use / runoff coefficient / soil K factor: I'm guessing you have a land use raster and the associated coefficients for different uses?

Comment: Thank you. I have created the listed data layers. What I am missing is the formula for calculating total runoff with these layers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate rainfall rasters for yourself you should have enough point-sample data and profound knowledge of interpolation techniques like spline interpolation or kriging. 
Therefore I would use data from NOAA instead as they are more reliable. If the resolution of these rasters is too coarse you may want to try a hybrid between interpolation and already available data.

Comment: thank you. I used spline to create a rainfall surface from 12 weather stations. I am stumped on a solid method to calculate total runoff from watershed using 1. rainfall, 2. landuse/coefficients, 3. flow accumulation.